# calculate one single z-score for a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, probability, distribution

I read to many different stuffs about how to calculate the z-score and I got confused. My question is : How can I get **one single** -zscore for a numeric vector in R?

I want to use the following equation

```
z_score=mean(x)/(standard_deviation(x)/square_root(size of vector(x)))
```

Example:

```
x <- c(235,453,182,564,435,356,765,234,562,123,454)

z_score=mean(x)/(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Any answer would be great.

Thanks

Comment: A z-score makes me think of a single point.  Do you want the z-score for each value in the vector to get back a vector of z-scores?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the test statistic of a z-test?

Comment: @duffymo and Roland, I need to calculate the confidance interval [link](http://pages.wustl.edu/montgomery/articles/2757). I could calculate the t-value by **qt** function but for z-value I do not how I can do that?

Comment: So, my guess was correct. Then your code appears to be correct.